# Angular js updating bound data on demand is not updating the template

Tags: angularjs

So I'm trying to build my first mobile app using html5, cordova, angularjs, and jQuery. I was able to create my controler and template with no problem. The data I bind to the template comes from a .net service formated in json. In my first version I loaded the data at the same time as the page load. In the second version I tried to make setting the data user driven. For some reason I don't understand my data is never applied to the template.

Please see this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/104/)**, outlining what does/doesn't work, and the templates

here is the js code that i'm testing with:

```
function DemoOnLoad($scope, $http) {
    $scope.workouts = [
        {Type:"Tempo", Details: [{Label:"Distance", Value:"5.1 Miles"}, {Label:"Pace", Value:"6.3 MPH"}]},
            {Type:"Long Run", "Details": [{Label:"Distance", Value:"13.1 Miles"}, {Label:"Pace", Value:"5.3 MPH"}]}
        ];
}

function DemoDynamic($scope, $http) {
    $scope.update = function () {
        $scope.workouts = [
            {Type:"Tempo", Details: [{Label:"Distance", Value:"5.1 Miles"}]},
             {"Type":"Long Run", "Details": [{Label:"Distance", Value:"13.1 Miles"}]}
        ];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your update is a method and you are calling it like a variable. you should use update() in your declarative not update.